# How to assign values to list in turtle onclick function

Tags: python, global-variables, turtle-graphics

In what is my first (fun) project using python I'm wrestling with this problem: I have four turtles which on click cycle through a set of color states. I need to find a way to feed back the last color state of each turtle to my program. The colors will be used as user input. 
So I set up a list, the turtles and a seperate function for each onclick, like so (shortened example):

```
u_choice = [a, b, c, d]

def color_change_one(x, y):
    global u_choice
    if t_one.color() == ('grey', 'grey'):
        t_one.color('red')
        u_choice[0] = 'red'
    elif t_one.color() == ('red', 'red'):
        t_one.color('blue')
        u_choice[0] = 'blue'    

t_one = turtle.Turtle()
t_one.shape('circle')
t_one.color('grey')
t_one.onclick(color_change_one)
```

What works fine is the color change on click, but u_choice does not get updated. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you checking if u_choice is being updated?

When I run this snippet, and click the turtle twice, and then `print u_choice` the output is 'blue'.

Comment: `import turtle
    u_choice = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

    def color_change_one(x, y):
        global u_choice
        if t_one.color() == ('grey', 'grey'):
            t_one.color('red')
            u_choice[0] = 'red'
        elif t_one.color() == ('red', 'red'):
            t_one.color('blue')
            u_choice[0] = 'blue'    

    t_one = turtle.Turtle()
    t_one.shape('circle')
    t_one.color('grey')
    t_one.onclick(color_change_one)

    print(u_choice)
    turtle.mainloop()` Result ist still ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

Comment: Are you clicking the turtle before printing u_choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `global u_choice` statement isn't needed as you're not changing the value of `u_choice`, just one of its elements.  Also, it's simpler to just test `.pencolor()` since `.color()` updates both pen and fill color.

Try this rework of your code.  It uses a timer as an indpendent printer of the `u_choice` variable.  You should see the change on the console as you cycle the turtle through it's three colors:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

u_choice = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def color_change_one(x, y):
    if t_one.pencolor() == 'grey':
        t_one.color('red')
    elif t_one.pencolor() == 'red':
        t_one.color('blue')
    elif t_one.pencolor() == 'blue':
        t_one.color('grey')

    u_choice[0] = t_one.pencolor()

screen = Screen()

t_one = Turtle('circle')
t_one.color('grey')
u_choice[0] = t_one.pencolor()

t_one.onclick(color_change_one)

def display():
    print(u_choice)
    screen.ontimer(display, 1000)

display()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! I probably haven't explained my problem well enough though. In your code when I do `print('u_choice',u_choice)` in the end, after clicking the turtle, I still get `u_choice ['grey', 'b', 'c', 'd']` when it should be red or blue.

Comment: Ok, thanks to your answer I've made some progress: I see that I can access the updated `u_choice` after `screen.mainloop()`, but not before. Not sure why that is, though. Also why is it that you get the updated list in your display function, but when I `print(u_choice)` in the line before or after the function, `u_choice` is not updated.

Comment: @rookie_senior, if you are simply putting the `print(u_choice)` statement after the call to `t_one.onclick(color_change_one)` and expecting the color to have changed then you are misunderstanding the whole dynamic of this program.  This is an event-based program, nothing happens until after the call to `screen.mainloop()` takes control and events and event handlers fire off in response to user actions.  The timer displays the changes as it plays in that event-based world.  And no, this doesn't mean you should put code after `screen.mainloop()`.  You need to think about the program differently.

Comment: this has brought more light in my confusion, thanks again. Actually this is one part of a larger program, which uses turtle graphics as user interface. So all is already wrapped in a `screen.mainloop()`. Right now I use `turtle.textinput()` to update `u_choice`, but that's rather awkward and error prone. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

When I run this:

```
import turtle
u_choice = ['blfsd']

def color_change_one(x, y):
    global u_choice
    if t_one.color() == ('grey', 'grey'):
        t_one.color('red')
        u_choice[0] = 'red'
    elif t_one.color() == ('red', 'red'):
        t_one.color('blue')
        u_choice[0] = 'blue'
    print u_choice

t_one = turtle.Turtle()
t_one.shape('circle')
t_one.color('grey')
t_one.onclick(color_change_one)
turtle.mainloop()
```

I see u_choice updating after each click. If you're checking the value of u_choice before clicking the turtle, it makes sense that it won't have updated u_choice yet.

Comment: unfortunately that is not the case, i. e printing u_choice after calling the function shows u_choice did not get updated

Comment: Yes, but you are printing u_choice inside the function, whereas I need to update u_choice globally, outside the function. The purpose of the onclick function is to collect user input ('Choose your colors')

Comment: To clarify, I mean I run this code and then run 'print u_choice' from an interactive terminal. I see the value of u_choice being updated.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, you are right, of course. I was confused about the structure of my program.